# Why is it allowed to reassign String but not *&String

Tags: rust, ownership

I understand String doesn't implement the `Copy` trait. So it cannot be moved. But I am failing to understand the difference between the following,

```
let greeting = String::from("Hello");
let temp = greeting; // This succeeds.

let greeting1 = String::from("Hello");
let temp1 = *&greeting1; // This fails to compile saying cannot move.
```

What is the difference between them ? Why one is valid and another is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I understand `String` doesn't implement the `Copy` trait. So it cannot be moved.

This is not really correct - values of all types can be moved, but you need to be the owner in order to move something. For example, if you write a function whose return type is `String`, when you return a value from this function, you are moving it (to the caller).

`Copy` is related to this in that a type implementing `Copy` allows you to implicitly convert a shared reference into an owned copy, which you are then allowed to move (since you own it).

> What is the difference between them ? Why one is valid and another is not?

`&greeting1` creates a shared reference to the string; the `String` value is not owned by the reference. So `*&greeting1` is a value of type `String` that you don't own, and you're not allowed to do anything with it that would require ownership.

Comment: Ah, got it. The reason why `let temp = greeting` would work is because the owner of the value tries to move it to a new owner. Which as you mentioned should work for any type irrespective of whether they implement Copy trait or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move out of references, and if you could, you would definitely not be able to move out of a *shared* reference because moving is a mutating operation.  So the code you should be testing is `let temp1 = *&mut greeting1;`, but this won't work either.

Moving out of references isn't supported because moving requires the compiler to be able to statically determine that the moved-from location is no longer used, and when references are in play the moved-from location isn't known -- the reference obfuscates this.

Consider:

```
fn foo(s: &mut String) {
    let x = *s;
}

fn bar() -> String {
    let s = String::new();
    foo(&mut s);
    s // What happens here?
}
```

How is `bar()` to know that `foo()` is going to steal the `s` value?  It can't know this.  When it attempts to use `s` after it was moved, there would be undefined behavior.

To prevent this from happening, only the *owner* of a value is allowed to move it.  A reference does not own a value; therefore moving out of a reference is forbidden.

Note that you *can* "steal" the value behind a mutable reference, but only if you have something to leave in its place.  For example, the built-in [`std::mem::take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) function will steal the value behind a mutable reference, *but* it requires that the type of the value being stolen implements `Default`, and it leaves the default value of the type in its place.  This way, you can move the value out of the reference, *and* the referent is still a valid value.

In your code, this would look like:

```
let temp1 = std::mem::take(&mut greeting1);
```

After this line, `temp1` will contain the value `greeting1` used to contain, and `greeting1` will be set to `<String as Default>::default()` (which would be an empty string).

Comment: That makes sense. Another question, `std::mem::take(&mut greeting1)` seems to actually do a bitwise copy of the underlying value. Is that what happens when the owner of the value moves it ? (i.e when we do `let temp = greeting;`

Comment: @mybloodtop Unless the move is elided, yes. In `let temp = greeting;` the compiler is almost certainly going to skip the move altogether as it's unnecessary. In cases where the move can't be elided, a simple bitwise copy is performed and the moved-from location is marked as such in the compiler so it can make sure you don't use it again later. The only difference when the moved-from value implements `Copy` is that the moved-from location _is not_ marked as moved-from. Otherwise, copying and moving are identical operations.